# Trying to get all post using wp_count_posts - WordPress PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function, attributes

I'm trying to get a list of authors on my site & their total posts.
All of this code is working, except the $count_posts($author->ID) part in the loop.
I think there may also be issues with my array for get_users - as I'm trying to more parts to the array.

```
function all_authors_list() {

    $authors = get_users(array(
        'role'      => 'subscriber',
        'orderby'   => 'post_count',
        'order'     => 'DESC',
        'number'    => '20',
        )   
    );

    $authors = $count_posts;
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts('page');
    $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;

    foreach($authors as $author) {
        echo '<div class="author-name">' . $author->first_name . ' ' . $author->last_name . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="author-post-count">' . $count_posts($author->ID) . '</div>';
    }
}
```

So the final output should be something like:
John Smith
20
Patricia Long
35
...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Write this below code in your post loop:

```
<p><?php the_author(); ?> has <?php echo number_format_i18n( get_the_author_posts() ); ?> 
posts</p>
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_posts

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use [`count_many_users_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_many_users_posts) to achieve that.

Basically you will get User's ID in to an array that is generated by the `$authors` and you can use that user ID in `count_many_users_posts`.

There is three parameters in [`count_many_users_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_many_users_posts) function and you can use `$post_type` parameter to get only pages.